# unable to send email from localhost

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to send mail from localhost with the following asp.net code..but email sending is becoming failed..

why is it so/???

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    string name = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    string contact = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
    mail.To.Add("email@gmail.com");

    mail.From = new MailAddress(name.Trim());


    mail.Subject = "In line image test";

    mail.Body = "Hello email...." +name.Trim() +", "+contact.Trim();

    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.EnableSsl = true; 
    client.Host = "127.0.0.1";
    client.Port = 25;

    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "abc");

    client.Credentials = credentials;

    try
    {

       client.Send(mail);
    }
    catch
    {

        Button1.Text = "Fail";

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you configured the smtp server?

Comment: What error do you get? Have you set up a local SMTP server? Please give some context.

Comment: @geek: yes, i have configured.

Comment: @alexn: `Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for email@gmail.com` i got this error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;

client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: thanks.. after doing this it shows that `message sent!` but on email id i didn't get any mail...

Comment: It's look like that all the mail are in** Queue** folder(**C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Queue**).Check **Queue** and let me know

Comment: One reason for this is that your ISP blocks port 25. You have to set up your ISP's SMTP server as Smarthost in your SMTP Virtual Server properties (tab Delivery -> Advanced) ...check out this link for how to setup smarthost http://www.petri.co.il/configure_iis_to_be_a_smart_host_for_exchange.htm

Comment: For `Configuring the domain for inbound` what i will have to give domain name??

Comment: how and what can i give domain name??

Comment: go to command prompt and type**ipconfig**.first entry is ur domain name

Comment: you want to send mail using localhost only?

Answer (score 0):

First setup the SMTP server in your local system, follow this link
http://www.arialsoftware.com/SetupSMTPServer.htm

Then you try your code, if you see the issue try to sort out and someone can help you.

Comment: `Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for email@gmail.com` i got this error..

Answer (score 0):

Please add below details in `Web.Config` file

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="FROM EMAIL ADDRESS">
        <network host="SERVER IP" userName="USER NAME" password="PASSWORD" port="25"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Hope it will help for you!